# What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

In general, if I had a laundry list of needs, restrictions, and desires that a particular application would need to address, but didn't know of a particular product name that would address those needs: what Stack Exchange site would be most relevant to post that question to in order to obtain software title suggestions that would qualify to suit the needs?

The industry that the software deals with is not a focus site with Stack Exchange as of yet.