# Asking for examples of programming languages with specific features

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions)

I am looking for a programming language that supports multiple inheritance as well as Java-like abstract classes. Would it be appropriate to ask for examples of (languages with specific features, like multiple inheritance) on Stack Overflow, or should these types of questions be posted elsewhere?

Comment: I don't know what is the official stand here, but you will get downvoted for this. BTW, Google can't help you with that?

Comment: I'm wondering if that question would fall under "too localized". It would only be of use to others also looking for languages with exactly those features. Then again, a broader question comparing programming language features might also not be a good fit. Hmm, not sure...

Comment: Wikipedia has several lists of programming language comparisons by the way. Start here for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

Comment: This is an example of the question I would ask: "Is there any programming language that supports named arguments as well as multiple inheritance?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of question is best decided using the site's [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

You will learn that this is not the best SO question because it contains no *source code*.

You will also learn that the question is still within the scope of the site because it concerns *tools commonly used by programmers*; and it is a *practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession*.

However, I would recommend googling an initial answer up; and ask questions on SO to check on what you have learned, and on questions that your research will undoubtedly provoke and that will be much harder to reliably answer without your *practical* knowledge of those particular languages.

That will not only make it a [better question](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html), but also better fit SO as you can see from its FAQ.  And you will get much further in your research.