# How to get product recommendations

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions)

I have a question of the form "what companies provide service X?"

I checked meta, and apparently such questions are highly discouraged on all Stack Exchange sites. Which is fine, but it obviously raises the meta-question: Where can I ask my question?

(In particular, I know that there are people hanging out on Stack Overflow who have probably needed the same service, so if an answer exists, they possess it...)

*Edit:* I should perhaps point out that the service I'm looking for is rather specific and slightly obscure. Otherwise, yeah, this would be a 10-second exercise with Google.

Comment: I think "product recommendations" is different that "provide service". The first you can find it on page with star-rates and see comments about products. The provide service is by looking and search on internet.

Comment: I have a memory that there used to be a meta question along the lines of "so where CAN I ask my {not good fit for stackexchange in general} question?", with quora, twitter, etc, as answers; but I can't find it now.

Comment: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

Comment: [Where in the (Stack Exchange) world can I initiate a programming-related discussion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124923/where-in-the-stack-exchange-world-can-i-initiate-a-programming-related-discuss) _"Where in the Stack Exchange universe does a question like the one above make the most sense? Is it just flat out unacceptable anywhere?..."_

Comment: There are now several StackExchanges for recommendations - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268486/253772

Answer (score 10):

The snarky answer: *Not here.*

The nice answer: *We're discouraging those questions throughout the whole network, sorry.*

The mean answer: *Yahoo Answers.*

The helpful answer: *Maybe in the chat.*

Comment: Shouldn't `Yahoo Answers` be the snarky answer and `Not here` the mean one? ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Have you ever been to Yahoo Answers?! It should be the *cruel* answer...

Comment: @UristMcBobby More like the unconstitutional answer. Pointing someone to Yahoo Answers definitely constitutes as "cruel and unusual punishment".

Comment: How is Babby Formed?

Comment: I think that this is an oversight. As a programmer, often you suspect a tool exists to achieve what you are about to start building, but are unable to find on Google due to the obscurity of the tool. E.g. "Does anyone know of a framework that does X". While google often can't help, other programmers can.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **Google**.

*What companies provide X?* is a quintessential Google question, it seems to me.

Comment: Google does not answer questions. It finds documents containing text similar to what you typed in. "How to use Google well" could be the topic for an entire book in its own right...

Comment: Google is great for finding advertised features of products, but sometimes there are some "show-stoppers" which cannot be found on Google unless you carefully study the fine print and user reviews for each product.

Comment: It's often pretty ineffective at answering questions like, "what products are capable of fulfilling my (pretty detailed specialized requirements) even in principle".