# Where can I ask for software suggestions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, asking-questions, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions)

Is there a Stack Exchange site where I can ask for software suggestions?