# Is this a resonable question to ask and if so which site to use?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for advice on this subject.  Surely, there are many developers who could offer a solid list.

Q: How do you help a junior programmer to develop longer-term thinking?

Books?  Mental/Design exercises?  Mentoring?  Ignore and hope they quit?  (Ok, that is short term on my part!)

- Trivial/Insane Example: How to convince not to copy/paste code between classes?

  - Me thinks: Why did we hire this person!?
- Less Trivial: How to convince to make a method part of a library with slightly more generic interface as it will help others later?

I am violating/failing-on one of Jeff's key points about good questions: "Write it well." (or something like that).  How do phrase a question to get good lists/ideas from experienced developers?

Please advise.

Comment: From the FAQ: "[To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where ... every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). The short answer is, you don't. Lists do not fit well into Q&A.

Comment: Related, most likely duplicate: [What Stack Exchange site would address software suggestion questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132890/what-stack-exchange-site-would-address-software-suggestion-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question attract lots of answers without a clear winner. In the past, we had lots of those. Most are closed, or put on historical lock.

Right now these questions are no longer wanted because of this.

Comment: I understand your concern.  Where can I ask this question?  A newsgroup?

Comment: Newsgroups and fora are good starts. As are some blogs. But use common sense. And don't forget, not each environment focus on best practices, but on profit. (There was a book question in the past).

Comment: Voila: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read/1713